# Writing a nested object to a module using fs does not show the nested contents (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects serving as a db in a file called transactions.js:

**transactions.js**

```
module.exports = {
transactions:
    [
       { "transactionID": "5520152942", "merchantName": "Thoughtstorm", "transactionAmt": 73, "transactionDt": "diam", "accountID": "0227761952", "customerID": "9174549049", "tags": [{ "tagId": "9174549049", "tagName": "Grocery" }, { "tagId": "2343432423", "tagName": "Dabfeed" }] },
       ....
    ]
```

In another file (mockServer.js) I require the data from transactions.js and mutate the data there as part of an API (e.g. POST, PUT, DELETE). I'm trying to update my transaction.js file every time one of those actions are performed. To do this, I've tried using fs as follows:

**mockServer.js**

```
const transactions = require('./assets/transaction');
const fs = require('fs');

// change the required transactions data

fs.writeFile('test.js', transactions.transactions, function (err, data) {
    console.log('transactions updated');
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

When I run this I get in my file:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

How would I be able to get the updated values of my transactions data into my file?

Thanks!

Comment: Call `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: As @robby mentioned use JSON.stringify(transactions.transactions)